# Как правильно: "Разговаривать со своими(о чем-либо) или между собой?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать: "Разговаривать со своими(о чем-либо) или между собой?

Comment: Не очень понятно что имеется в виду. Вот в заголовке, например, только одна кавычка. Вы о двух выражениях спрашиваете или об одном?

Comment: Да, очень сомнительно, что автор именно так ставил вопрос, как его понял Серж. У меня такое ощущение, что это одна хитромудрая фраза такая. У носителя языка не должно бы возникать какого-то противопоставления фраз с настолько разным смыслом ("со своими" и "между собой"). Разве если только русский совсем "не родной"

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идёт об отдельном участнике разговора, то он *разговаривает со своими собеседниками*, а если обо всех вместе участниках разговора, то они *разговаривают (между собой)*. "Между собой" есть смысл упоминать только в отдельных случаях (например, если нужно пояснить, что кто-то из присутствующих в разговоре не участвует).